# change url for store view

Tags: multistore, url, store-view, redirect-url

I have Magento 2.3.3 I created store views French, English, Turkish. I want to change url,.
 for  example http://localhost:8080/magento/fr for French store 
              http://localhost:8080/magento/tr for Turkish store

but after edit, the page in not load. This for Turkish store

[image]

how I can specify custom URL  for store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the Admin panel, click **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web**.
2. From the Store View list at the top of the page, click the name of one of your websites as the following figure shows.

[image]

3. In the right pane, expand Base URLs.
4. In the Base URLs section, clear Use system value.
5. Enter the http://french.magento.mg URL in the Base URL and Base Link URL fields.
6. Repeat the previous step in the Base URLs (Secure) section.
7. Click Save Config.
8. Repeat these tasks for other websites.

Comment: Hi. Same problem page  not load

Comment: Please run the rm - rf var/cache and finally run the deploy command for all language